# Get around MaxReceivedMessageSize limits

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm writing a console app which downloads reports from an external server daily via an API. I'm having problems with the MaxReceivedMessageSize size limit, as I'm always exceeding the value set there (in app.config).

This value seems unable to be reset, as I've tried doing it programatically, and it even starts off from where it's left off on a computer restart.

Is there a way to get around this? Below is the app.config file where the values are set:

```
<binding name="ReportingSoap" closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="64000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        </security>
```

Comment: I've successfully fixed problems by increasing both maxReceivedMessageSize and maxStringContentLength in the past.  How long are your reports?  Maybe you just need to make the numbers bigger.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, define `serviceBehaviours` as:

```
<serviceBehaviours>
      <behavior name="servicebehaviour">
           <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="655360000" />
      </behavior>
</serviceBehaviours>
```

And use it in the service tag:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="servicebehaviour"  ....>
```

Similarly, on the client side, you've to define `endpointBehaviors` as:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="custombehaviour">
           <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="655360000" />
      </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

And use this in the `endpoint`:

```
<endpoint behaviorConfiguration="custombehaviour" ...../>
```